# selecting distinct values from master table and repeated values from joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select distinct values from master table and repeated values from child tables.
I have 4 tables:

1. invoice
2. invoiceLine
3. product
4. businessPartner

My query:

```
select 
c_invoice.c_invoice_ID,
c_bpartner.name as "Business Partner",
M_Product.name as "Product",
c_invoiceline.priceentered as "amount"
 from adempiere.c_invoice 
 left join adempiere.c_invoiceline on c_invoice.c_invoice_ID=c_invoiceline.c_invoice_ID
 left join adempiere.M_Product on c_invoiceline.M_Product_ID =M_Product.M_Product_ID
 left join adempiere.C_BPartner on c_invoice.c_bpartner_ID=c_bpartner.c_bpartner_id
 where c_invoice.sh_booking_ID=1000019 and c_invoice.c_doctypetarget_id=1000005
```

My query result:

```
INVOICEID   BUSINESS Partner    PRODUCT     AMT 
1000005;    "Tehmoor";          "Charge 1"; 1200
1000005;    "Tehmoor";          "Standard"; 1500
1000006;    "Rafay";            "Charge 1"; 1200
1000006;    "Rafay";            "Standard"; 1100
```

and expected result

```
INVOICEID   BUSINESS Partner    PRODUCT     AMT 
1000005;    "Tehmoor";          "Charge 1"; 1200
      ;      NULL;              "Standard"; 1500
1000006;    "Rafay";            "Charge 1"; 1200
       ;    NULL;               "Standard"; 1100
```

Comment: you have "BUSINESS Partner" -eq null in second and fourth rows in expected result - why?..

Comment: It's logical, since invoices are created for single business partners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select 
  CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY mast.id) = 1 THEN
    mast.title
  ELSE NULL END as title,
  joined.measure
from mast
left join joined on (mast_id = mast.id)
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/434f1/2) for it, so you can examine my example schema.
I think it's better to handle this kind of requirement in a host language, because in SQL it's a bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you buddy, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your schema in my local environment. Below is the query using which you can achieve your desired result.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (Rank() Over(ORDER BY i.c_invoice_id ASC)) = (Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY i.c_invoice_id ASC)) THEN pt.b_name ELSE NULL END AS "Business Partner",
CASE WHEN (Rank() Over(ORDER BY i.c_invoice_id ASC)) = (Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY i.c_invoice_id ASC)) THEN i.c_invoice_id ELSE NULL END AS Invoice_Id,
pr.b_name,
il.price  
FROM  invoice i
LEFT JOIN c_invoice_line il ON il.c_invoice_id = il.c_invoice_id
LEFT JOIN c_product pr ON il.product_line_id = pr.b_prod_id
LEFT JOIN c_bpartner pt ON pt.b_partner_id =  Trim(il.c_prod_id);
```

If required, change your table and column names accordingly.